# CakePdf not showing proper layout in live server

Tags: html, css, cakephp-3.0, dompdf

Hi I am using CakePDF to generate HTML to PDF files all files are generating good in localhost but when I moved them to live server than exact layout is not showing. Inline css is used with table tab.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What PDF engine are you using? You could try a different one and see if the problem persists (not a solution, but a work-around). What are differences between your dev and production server?

Comment: @Roberto 22 thanks I change one cache file and my code works thanks

Comment: Cool. It would be great if you could add that as an answer.